# Grab $_GET like in PHP but in Visual Basic?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web browser called WebBrowser1 and I want to be able to detect the $_GET like i would be able to in PHP and place it in a Textlabel

Like if the url was:

> www.example.com/page.php?myget=true

Is it possible to Visual Basic to grab what ever is in 'myget'. I'm a bit new at the this so please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
Request.QueryString("myget")
```

for properties on the querystring.

Request.Form() would get you posted params

and Request.Params() will get params from both.

Comment: When I type 'Request' I get an error saying 'Request' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Are you trying access it in the code behind or markup? In the code behind the page or control base class gives you the current request object. It's possible to reach it via system.web.httpcontext.current.request from anywhere. (Provided you've got all your references and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are running a webforms VB.net application.

First you'll need to add a reference to System.Web

Then use the following code to read the querystring from the browser uri and parse it into a collection of name value pairs. If you don't want to include System.Web you could write your own code to do it based on the value of WebBrowser1.Uri.Query

```
Dim queryString As String = webBrowser1.Url.Query
Dim queryStringValues As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
Dim lolValue As String = queryStringValues("lol")
```