# Grab $_GET like in PHP but in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grab $_GET like in PHP but in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624318/grab-get-like-in-php-but-in-visual-basic)

I have a web browser called WebBrowser1 and I want to be able to detect the $_GET like i would be able to in PHP and place it in a Textlabel

Like if the url was:

www.thisurl.com/page.php?lol=grabthis

Is it possible to Visual Basic to grab what ever is in 'lol'. I'm a bit new at the this so please let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VB6? Are you talking about a client application (embedding IE) or an ASP.NET server app?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are running a webforms VB.net application.

First you'll need to add a reference to System.Web

Then use the following code to read the querystring from the browser uri and parse it into a collection of name value pairs. If you don't want to include System.Web you could write your own code to do it based on the value of WebBrowser1.Uri.Query

```
Dim queryString As String = webBrowser1.Url.Query
Dim queryStringValues As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
Dim lolValue As String = queryStringValues("lol")
```